# Extending devise recoverable to add username reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-recoverable

With Devise, we have recoverable for resetting passwords, however, I need to implement a username reset using the same flow as the password reset.

Is this possible to do with Devise or do I have to do this from scratch? And if so how do I go about extending and adding the new reset option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to start from scratch since updating the username is part of the updating a normal user. If you want the same flow (sending a link to the email with a unique token etc), you might want to develop your own.

The [wiki has an article](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/Lockdown-Username-Change) on the opposite of what you want to do though.